# jsf and url-pattern of the web.xml file

Tags: jsf

I am developing a web app using jsf technology. I want a method of my backing bean to be
invoked when the home page of my app is displayed. Usually, a backing bean method 
gets involved when a user clicks on a link or a button.

In short I want my backing bean to get some data from the database and send it to the 
jsf page, and I want this to occur when a user invokes the home page link
of my app.

Here is how I wanted to solve the problem: use a servlet that is executed when
the expected link is invoked, and call the backing bean from that servlet; but the problem
is I am having some difficulties with the url-pattern of the servlet in the web.xml file. The home page link of my app is: home.jsf. The name of my servlet is
HomeServlet and here is how I configured it in the web.xml file:

```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>HomeServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>utils.HomeServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>HomeServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/home.jsf</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

So when I run the app, the servlet is executed, but my home.jsf page is empty (completely blank). I don't know why.

So what I want to know is:

- Am I using the right approach for this issue?
- If yes, which url-pattern should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is definitely not the right approach. You're working your way around JSF. You're supposed to do the job just in the constructor or `@PostConstruct` method of the request or view scoped JSF managed bean associated with the view.

E.g.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Home {

    public Home() {
        // Here.
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Or here. This will be invoked *after* any dependency injections,
        // such as @EJB, @ManagedProperty, @Inject, @Resource, etc.
    }

    // ...
}
```

Whenever JSF encounters a `#{home.someproperty}` reference in the `home.xhtml` (or `home.jsp`) for the first time, then the bean will just be constructed.

When developing with JSF, you shouldn't have any need to develop other servlets. In JSF, the `FacesServlet` is the sole servlet which already does all the necessary request/response and model/view controlling job.